# 類似ユーザをレコメンドする際のシステム設計について

Tags: ruby, python

例を挙げて説明します。
たとえば、A,B,Cという3ユーザがいて、それぞれじゃんけんでグーチョキパーを出す確率が、

> A: 20 30 50
>   B: 60 20 20
>   C: 20 40 40

だとします。(数字は%で、トータルは100%固定)

この場合、AとBよりAとCのほうが似た手を出すといえると思うので、
Cというユーザをレコメンドしたいです。

これを毎回計算すると、計算量が多く速度が出ないのではと懸念しています。
ユーザごとの類似度を事前に計算しておき、別テーブルに格納するなどは思いつくのですが、
他によい手法等ありましたら教えて頂きたいです。

ポイントとしては、

1. トータルの値は固定で、カラム数も決まっている(今回でいうと、グーチョキパーを集計すると100%)
2. 機能としては類似ユーザをレコメンドするのみ
3. ユーザ数は1万人ほど

という感じです。

動作サーバはまだ決めていないので、スペックは出せません。
言語としてはPythonかRubyで、Webサービスを考えています。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 引き分けの確率を最大化する?

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
すみません、わかりませんでした...。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webサービスの場合は、REDISのようなキャッシュを使うといいと思います。
DJANGOのようなWEBフレームワークを使った場合、そのための関数デコレータがすでに用意されていますが、自分で作るのは難しくないですね。

redisを使った例：

```
import redis

cache = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

def redis_cache_decorator(f):
    """Redis Cache Decorator"""
    def cache_func(*args):
        key = '-'.join(repr(arg) for arg in args)
        result = cache.get(key)
        if result is None:
            result = f(*args)
            cache.set(key, result)
        else:  
            result = int(result)  # redisの場合、bytesとした返されるので、変換が必要
            print('cache hit!') # for demo only!
        return result
    return cache_func

@redis_cache_decorator
def process_heavy_func(v1, v2):
    # 処理行う
    return v1 - v2

process_heavy_func(9, 2)  # 結果が計算されて、キャッシュされる
process_heavy_func(9, 2)  # 同じargsを渡すとキャッシュされた値が返される　（cache hit!が表示）
```

関数デコレータについて
http://www.lifewithpython.com/2014/12/python-decorator-syntax.html

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。  
キャッシュサーバに計算結果を持たしておくという方法ですね。  
参考にさせていただきます。  

※この観点だと、  
http://qiita.com/haminiku/items/ca7eec8ed09982aec9b5  
辺りがやりたいことに近そうですね。  
(このケースよりノードも浅く単純ですが)